# How to use values from table column as field names in SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

Scenario:

**Field names of Table1 named as testtable**

id,name,size,width,height

**Field names of Table2 named as errortable**

id,desc,field1,field2,operator

**Values of errortable**

```
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
| id |                desc                 | field1 | field2 | operator |
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
|  1 | size should not greater than width  | size   | width  | >        |
|  2 | size should not greater than height | size   | height | >        |
|  3 | with should be equal to height      | width  | height | <>       |
+----+-------------------------------------+--------+--------+----------+
```

Now I want to check from `testtable`:

1. count all those records where size > width.
2. count all those records where size > height.
3. count all those records where width <> height.

**Required Output**

```
+-------------------------------------+-------+
|              errorname              | count |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
| size should not greater than width  |     6 |
| size should not greater than height |     2 |
| with should be equal to height      |     3 |
+-------------------------------------+-------+
```

Is it possible to do like this?

Current query:

```
select desc,
  (select count(*) as "Total Errors" 
   from testtable 
   where errortable.field1 errortable.operator errortable.field2 ) 
from errortable group by id;
```

Comment: Please check the formatting tools and make your post cleaner.  Also, please clarify if you are using PostgreSQL or MySQL.

Comment: I need this query in two applications, one is using postgress and second is using mysql.

Comment: Please provide SHOW CREATE TABLE xxxx\G (MySQL) and \d xxxx fo the PostgreSQL ones. Some sample data and the desired result would also be of use.

Answer (score 5):

#### Assumptions and Clarification

- **Postgres 9.4** (or later)
- You want various counts from the same given table.

<strike>`desc`</strike> is a reserved word in SQL, don't use it as identifier. Using `descr` instead.

#### 1. Basic query

The fastest and most elegant way to get multiple partial counts from the same table is a single `SELECT` statement with multiple aggregate functions using the `FILTER` clause:

- [Return counts for multiple ranges in a single SELECT statement](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/93510/return-counts-for-multiple-ranges-in-a-single-select-statement/93522#93522)

A statement like:

```
SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE size > width)    AS ct1
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE size > height)   AS ct2
     , count(*) FILTER (WHERE width <> height) AS ct3
FROM   testtable;
```

Or, for Postgres 9.3:

```
SELECT count(size > width OR NULL)    AS ct1
     , ...
FROM   testtable;
```

#### 2. Advanced query

To get the result in the form you want it, unpivot with a `VALUES` expression in a `LATERAL` join, adding the ID and description `id, descr` in the process:

```
SELECT x.*
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) FILTER (WHERE size > width)    AS ct1
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE size > height)   AS ct2
        , count(*) FILTER (WHERE width <> height) AS ct3
   FROM   testtable
   ) t
, LATERAL (
   VALUES (1, 'size should not greater than width' , ct1)
        , (2, 'size should not greater than height', ct2)
        , (3, 'with should be equal to height'     , ct3)
   ) x(id, descr, ct);
```

**Bold** parts come from the `errortable` when building the statement dynamically:

#### 3. Dynamic query

To concatenate the above statement dynamically from values provided in `errortable`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
SELECT 'SELECT x.* FROM (SELECT '
    || string_agg(
         format('count(*) FILTER (WHERE %I %s %I) AS c%s'
              , field1, operator, field2, id)
       , ', ')
    || ' FROM testtable) t, LATERAL (VALUES ('
    || string_agg(format('%s, %L, c%s', id, descr, id), '), (')
    || ')) x(id, dscr, ct)'
FROM   errortable;
```

`format()` with `%I` quotes column names where necessary and makes the statement safe against **SQL injection** - except for `operator`, which is concatenated as is. You might be able to make that safe, too, with the [`OPERATOR()` construct](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-EXPRESSIONS-OPERATOR-CALLS) ...

If untrusted users don't have write access to `errortable`, you can control its content and need not worry.

#### 4. Full automation

Since the return type is uniform and well known, we can encapsulate it in a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_error_count()
  RETURNS TABLE (id int, descr text, ct bigint)
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE (
   SELECT format('SELECT x.* FROM (SELECT %s FROM testtable) t
                        , LATERAL (VALUES (%s)) x(id, dscr, ct)'
               , string_agg(format('count(*) FILTER (WHERE %I %s %I) AS c%s'
                                 , e.field1, e.operator, e.field2, e.id), ', ')
               , string_agg(format('%s, %L, c%s', e.id, e.descr, e.id), '), ('))
   FROM   errortable e
   );
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM f_error_count();
```

Simplifying the concatenation by one more step with an outer `format()`. Also note how all columns are table-qualified to avoid conflicts.
Again, since dynamic SQL is involved, make sure it cannot be abused for SQL injection.

- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)
- [Permission for sequence in another schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76131/permission-for-sequence-in-another-schema/76160#76160)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=90e1d4e63ebb1b11a3f0a3fae9171d61)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/8a27c)</sub>