# What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?

Tags: postgresql, functions, postgresql-14

On PG 14's documentation, in the `CREATE FUNCTION` section, the manual says that the body of a `LANGUAGE SQL` function can either be a single statement:

```
RETURN expression
```

or a block:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
statement;
statement;
...
statement;
END
```

without giving any explanation of the semantics of that block.  This looks similar to a `BEGIN ... END;` block in PL/pgSQL, but seems to be something different.

What's the difference between writing a set of statements within or without `BEGIN ATOMIC ... END`?  When is it necessary to use such a block?  Is the `ATOMIC` keyword mandatory?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's the new (in Postgres 14) syntax variant for **SQL-standard functions**.
[The release notes:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/release-14.html#id-1.11.6.7.5.8)

> Allow SQL-language functions and procedures to use SQL-standard function bodies (Peter Eisentraut)

> Previously only string-literal function bodies were supported. When writing a function or procedure in SQL-standard syntax, the body is parsed immediately and stored as a parse tree. This allows better tracking of function dependencies, and can have security benefits.

Traditional Postgres functions and procedures save the body as literal string to be parsed at execution time, typically using dollar-quoting. See:

- [What are '$$' used for in PL/pgSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12172353/939860)

The new syntax `BEGIN ATOMIC ... END` (with mandatory `ATOMIC`!) does not quote the function body, which is parsed at creation time. It only *looks* similar to a PL/pgSQL block, which is decorated with `BEGIN ... END`. Both are very much distinct. The new syntax variant is only allowed for `LANGUAGE sql`. In fact, that language is assumed without declaration. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.67.6)

> The default is `sql` if ***`sql_body`*** is specified.

You can write multiple pure-SQL statements, much like in traditional string-literal function or procedure bodies. But everything is parsed at function-creation time. So "early binding" vs. "late binding" for the traditional string-literal form. This has a number of side effects.
There is good explanation for SQL-standard syntax the [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.67.6):

> This is similar to writing the text of the function body as a string
> constant (see ***definition*** above), but there are some differences:
> This form only works for `LANGUAGE SQL`, the string constant form
> works for all languages. This form is parsed at function definition
> time, the string constant form is parsed at execution time; therefore
> this form cannot support polymorphic argument types and other
> constructs that are not resolvable at function definition time. This
> form tracks dependencies between the function and objects used in the
> function body, so `DROP ... CASCADE` will work correctly, whereas the
> form using string literals may leave dangling functions. Finally, this
> form is more compatible with the SQL standard and other SQL implementations.

The "SQL-standard" form can also be "inlined". See:

- [How can I find out if a SQL function can be inlined?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/212198/how-can-i-find-out-if-a-sql-function-can-be-inlined/212199#212199)

The new syntax variant will typically be preferable for simple SQL functions.

##### Code examples

**Short form** for a **single expression** with `RETURN` (and no `ATOMIC` keyword):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asterisk(n int)
  RETURNS text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
RETURN repeat('*', n);
```

**Full form:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asterisks(n int)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT repeat('*', g) FROM generate_series (1, n) g;
END;
```

For reference, the same as traditional SQL function with string-literal body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asterisks(n int)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT repeat('*', g) FROM generate_series (1, n) g;
$func$;
```

Or as PL/pgSQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION asterisks(n int)
  RETURNS SETOF text
  LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT repeat('*', g) FROM generate_series (1, n) g;
END
$func$;
```

Comment: "*This form tracks dependencies between the function and objects used in the function body*" - does that mean it also tracks renames? And is no longer susceptible to shadowing through `search_path`, [like default expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068040/1048572)?

Comment: @Bergi: That's what it means, among other things. The function body is parsed at creation time, the original function body string isn't even saved (means you lose formating and comments in the function body!) - as opposed to the traditional `CREATE FUNCTION` syntax that saves the given body as string literal for call-time parsing etc. Early binding vs. Late binding, each has its advantages.