# Efficient unique Inner Join

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, execution-plan, postgresql-performance

#### Context

I have a query that is *something like* where I want to query all of the days that each product was on sale at at *least 1 store*. This query runs as part of a larger query and runs whenever a user loads a specific page.

#### TL;DR Schema and query

(data is for example purposes only)

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0ad70a90a446e811e08aa1bd779550d1

#### Schema

I have a table `sales_periods` that tracks the *date* periods that products were on sale at each store.

| product_id | since | till | store_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | Aug 12, 2016 | Jan 27, 2018 | 19 |
| 42 | Jan 1, 2020 | Jan 27, 2021 | 19 |
| 43 | Feb 14, 2019 | Jan 27, 2022 | 20 |

#### Query

```
WITH dates(day) AS(
  SELECT day FROM calendar WHERE day BETWEEN '2021-04-14'::date AND '2022-04-13'::date
)
SELECT
  sales_periods.product_id,
  COUNT(DISTINCT dates.day)
FROM
  sales_periods
  INNER JOIN dates ON dates.day >= sales_periods.since
  AND dates.day <= sales_periods.till
GROUP BY
  sales_periods.product_id
```

#### The problem

There could be 100s of stores and 10,000s of products. And I want to look at an entire year! From what I think I see from `EXPLAIN`, Postgres will do the JOIN (creating a lot of data in memory = 100 stores x 10,000 products x 365 days) and then it will reduce the data with the group (max 10,000 products x 365 days).

#### Goal

I would like the query to run <100ms. I think <<50ms is possible if the query can be made properly. I can see what it's doing is wrong but I don't know how to do better!

#### What I've tried

1. Combining the sales_periods <- Takes too much time compared with the amount of time saved
2. Use DISTINCT ON instead of GROUP BY <- slower
3. Switching to daterange (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=55fa23c2bbb7d44374ef6ab2acc570a2) <- slower
4. I played around a lot with the indexes, including trying out GIST indexes, sorted index, etc. <- no change, sometimes worse

#### What I think I want

If there's a way to tell Postgres to *stop* as soon as it knows that *each* product is available for purchase from at least *1* store on *each* day.

#### Environment

Postgres 13

#### Constraints

It would be very hard to *change* the column structure of the sales_periods table but it could be done. Adding and removing columns, adding index and views are all easy.

Comment: You will have to generate a realistic amount of test data. Then you can easily experiment and find the best solution.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Even just 1000 rows demonstrates the problem pretty well I think. Check my dbfiddle.uk link

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl  Illustrating the problem isn't the same thing as finding the solution.  The solution is likely to be entirely different for 1000 rows than for 1000000.

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to be running this over and over again with different parameters.  Why then does it need to finish in <50ms?

Comment: @jjanes The dbfiddle query does replicate what I'm seeing locally with real data. So what that says to me is that there's a problem with how they query is being approached. You're right that seeing the problem isn't the same as finding a solution. But it's a necessary beginning :). What do you mean about "over and over again with different parameters"?. I would like <50ms because this query is part of a larger query that needs to run when a user requests a webpage (motivation added).

Comment: Maybe postgres might compute the date inclusion faster with a [daterange](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/rangetypes.html) column on `sales_periods` using `start` and `till`,  join with `<@`, Gist(ish) index on the daterange column. Not tested!

Comment: Thank you for the idea, @mcadorel . Unfortunately it somehow made it worse. I tried it here https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=eec48cd6ed55e944ed02ea337e17ba04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of indexes that might help a query of your kind. Like, a btree index with inverted sort order (possibly multicolumn, or "covering"). See:

- [Optimizing queries on a range of timestamps (two columns)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589/optimizing-queries-on-a-range-of-timestamps-two-columns/39599#39599)

Or a GiST or SP-GiST index on `daterange`. See:

- [Perform this hours of operation query in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22111524/939860)

However, while your filters are hardly selective, indexes can only do so much. What makes your query expensive is "unnesting" rows with long time ranges to **many** rows before folding duplicate days with `DISTINCT` and counting. That can be improved ***gradually***.

#### Faster `EXISTS` variant

[Your attempt at an `EXISTS` query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e81678ab24633937116d87d3a40f2e5a) has an expensive flaw. You still `COUNT(DISTINCT dates.day)`, but there's no need any more as `EXISTS` already eliminated duplicates. `count(*)` is substantially faster. Plus some other minor modifications:

```
WITH dates AS (
   SELECT day FROM calendar
   WHERE  day BETWEEN '2021-04-14' AND '2022-04-13'
   )
SELECT p.product_id, count(*) AS days
FROM   dates d
CROSS  JOIN products p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM sales_periods s
   WHERE  s.product_id = p.product_id
   AND    d.day >= s.since
   AND    d.day <= s.till
   )
GROUP  BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e1dd0550ead55a4450a8bb953219d51a)*

#### Pre-select rows from `sales_periods`

Another possible optimization, especially while indexes on the main table don't help anyway, or for more selective filter ranges: eliminate irrelevant sales early:

```
WITH s AS (
   SELECT product_id, since, till
   FROM   sales_periods
   WHERE  since <= '2022-04-13'
   AND    till  >= '2021-04-14'
   )
SELECT p.product_id, count(*) AS days
FROM  (
   SELECT day FROM calendar
   WHERE  day BETWEEN '2021-04-14' AND '2022-04-13'
   ) d
CROSS  JOIN products p
WHERE  EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM s
   WHERE  s.product_id = p.product_id
   AND    d.day >= s.since
   AND    d.day <= s.till
   )
GROUP BY 1;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e1dd0550ead55a4450a8bb953219d51a)*

Aside:
Your `calendar` table holds days till the year 2222, which seems like excessive waste. There is no need to handle a table of 81083 rows. But that's a minor issue.

### Much faster with range aggregation

What I really want to post is the following query making use of range aggregation, and then count the days in the range. **200x faster** in my hands with your sample data (~ 3 ms vs ~ 650 ms for your original query). But there's a snag: we need multiranges introduced with **Postgres 14**.

Create this **auxiliary function** to count days in a `datemultirange`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_days_in_multirange(datemultirange)
  RETURNS int
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT sum(upper(r) - lower(r))::int
FROM   unnest($1) t(r);
END;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION f_days_in_multirange(datemultirange) IS 'Counts days in given datemultirange.
Input with any unbounded range results in NULL value!';
```

See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC ... END mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300507/what-does-begin-atomic-end-mean-in-a-postgresql-sql-function-procedure/300512#300512)

Then the query can be:

```
SELECT product_id
     , CASE WHEN sales_ct = 1 THEN upper(date_range) - lower(date_range)
            ELSE f_days_in_multirange(date_range) END AS days
FROM  (
   SELECT product_id, count(*) AS sales_ct
        , range_agg(daterange(since, till, '[]'))
        * multirange(daterange('2021-04-14', '2022-04-13', '[]')) AS date_range        
   FROM   sales_periods
   WHERE  since <= '2022-04-13'
   AND    till  >= '2021-04-14'
   GROUP  BY 1
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e1dd0550ead55a4450a8bb953219d51a)*

Most of your resulting date ranges consist of a *single* range, and most of those come from a single source. So I added a cheap count `sales_ct` and used that to take a shortcut to great effect (almost 10x). `CASE WHEN sales_ct = 1 THEN ...`. Depending on your actual data distribution, other shortcuts may be possbile.

You need to understand [range and multirange types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html#RANGETYPES-BUILTIN), [range aggregation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE), and the [(multi-)range operator `anyrange * anyrange → anyrange`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-range.html#RANGE-OPERATORS-TABLE) to compute the intersection of the ranges.

Comment: OMG, you coming here is like a celebrity visiting! I was looking at your answers to other questions to see how they might relate and trying different things! I even tried to find your contact information to see if I could hire you for this question, hahaha! But you seemed like a private person who doesn't do that kind of thing. I'm not at my computer right now but I look forward to digesting your answer and lessons

Comment: @hrdwdmrbl: Oh, I do PostgreSQL consulting for a living. I just removed all contact data here because private messages got out of hand. I hope Postgres 14 is an option for you.

Comment: Interesting! I literally searched for you online and didn't find much... I found what I thought was your linkedin but nothing there... Anyway, I just had time to digest your INCREDIBLE feedback! THANK YOU SO MUCH! I will definitely switch to an EXISTS-based query. I also changed your dbfiddle a bit to always use Calendar https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=d41a734a5d40ede2e5ec5336369eaf7b
I was going to also ask about https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/39589 but then I realized that you did also play around with indexes as well and saw that they were mostly unhelpful.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter  polymorphic/generic function of f_days_in_multirange also works.

Comment: @Mark: Kind of. The expression `sum(upper(r) - lower(r))::int` only works for some range types.

Answer (score 1):

In your example data, most products are only sold in one store.  How does this compare to your real data?  Will that matrix be dense?  Will it be over populated (multiple different ranges per store/product pairing)?

If this exists as part of a larger query, maybe the best optimization opportunities only exist in the context of that larger query.

You said that combining ranges took too much time.  Why would you have to do that for every execution?  Store the combined ranges (or for that matter, the results of this query) in a materialized view which is only refreshed daily.

> If there's a way to tell Postgres to stop as soon as it knows that each product is available for purchase from at least 1 store on each day.

Yes, but since each product times each day >= 3,650,000, I doubt this will actually be as fast as you are hoping.  You can get a semi-join by using `EXISTS (...)`.

This formulation requires you to have a table named "products" which lists each product, which I assume you have already.

```
SELECT
    product_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT dates.day)
FROM generate_series(<START_DATE>, <END_DATE>, '1 day'::interval) AS dates(day)
CROSS JOIN products
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 from sales_periods 
    WHERE sales_periods.product_id=products.product_id
    AND dates.day >= sales_periods.since
    AND dates.day <= sales_periods.till
)
GROUP BY
    product_id
```

So it is possible, but as I said I don't think it will have the benefit you want.

By the way, in your fiddle to show the usage of daterange type, you didn't add the GiST index to index it. I doubt that it would make much difference anyway, but it is rather unfair to not even try it.

Comment: I felt bad that my question was already SO LONG, but the reason I can't store the combined ranges is because in some queries, store_id is used. So in those cases, the query is even faster because we're eliminating many sales_periods rows, but the query is still too slow in that case.

Comment: I also implemented your suggestion here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=c02df55057da21eb781be529d1b4f90d

It does look like it isn't faster.

NOTE: I found one small optimization on my own which was to actually make a calendar table with an index (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=e81678ab24633937116d87d3a40f2e5a) and I used that with your suggestion

Answer (score -7):

There is two problems in your query...

**FIRST** generating data on the fly by using *generate_series* is a bad trick that will drag down performances... To optimize a query, the optimizer (planer in PostGreSQL terminology...) must know how many rows will be used in every table, before executing the query, thus to build a good execution plan, that will be used to solve the "demand". It is impossible to know in advance the number of rows with *generate_series* because this number will be known, after executing the function... This trouble is known as an X/Y problem...

**SECOND**, due to MVCC, PostGreSQL is unnable to perform a quick execution of a COUNT because it have to check every rows in every pages of the table to do so, while professionnal RDBMS like Oracle or MS SQL Server does not need to read everything, only the header of the pages that contains exact "live" rows...

To see the difference in terms of performances between SQL Server and PostGreSQL for COUNT queries, [read the benchmark I have made...](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/) You can reproduce the benchmark I have used for your own purpose... The differences are quite important (between 61 and 1,533 times faster for SQL Server)

Comment: The generated data on the fly is dummy data needed to illustrate the problem. Also I don't think switching DBs is the answer. I'm certain that there are multiple ways to perform the query efficiently but I just don't know them yet

Comment: Your second point is incorrect.