# Function returns one row, but the query it wraps returns many

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, functions, set-returning-functions

A very odd situation, where a query returns 1380 items, but when wrapped in a function, then same function returns a single row

I've tried deleting and recreating the function.

When called like this, via a function, 1 row is returned.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_temps(tid uuid) RETURNS uuid
    LANGUAGE sql
AS
$$
    WITH RECURSIVE
        start_set (temp_id, display_name, parent_temp_id) AS
            (SELECT t.temp_id, t.display_name, t.parent_temp_id
             FROM temps t
             WHERE t.temp_id = tid),
        subitems (temp_id, display_name, parent_temp_id) AS
            (SELECT s.temp_id, s.display_name, s.parent_temp_id
             FROM start_set s
             UNION ALL
             SELECT t.temp_id, t.display_name, t.parent_temp_id
             FROM temps t
             JOIN subitems subs ON t.parent_temp_id = subs.temp_id)
    SELECT temp_id
    FROM subitems;
$$;
```

When called not-in-a-function-wrapper, it returns 1380 rows

```sql
    WITH RECURSIVE
        start_set (temp_id, display_name, parent_temp_id) AS
            (SELECT t.temp_id, t.display_name, t.parent_temp_id
             FROM temps t
             WHERE t.temp_id = tid),
        subitems (temp_id, display_name, parent_temp_id) AS
            (SELECT s.temp_id, s.display_name, s.parent_temp_id
             FROM start_set s
             UNION ALL
             SELECT t.temp_id, t.display_name, t.parent_temp_id
             FROM temps t
             JOIN subitems subs ON t.parent_temp_id = subs.temp_id)
    SELECT temp_id
    FROM subitems;
```

What am I not thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return a set of values (or set of rows) it must be a **set-returning function**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_temps(tid uuid)
  RETURNS SETOF uuid  -- !!!
  LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
...
$func$;
```

Now it can return 0-n rows. That includes returning nothing at all ("no row"). The way you declared it, it's a "scalar" function, always returning a single value. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createfunction.html#id-1.9.3.67.6)

> The `SETOF` modifier indicates that the function will return a set of items, rather than a single item.

See (with links to more):

- [PL/pgSQL function does not return all the results using record](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48533292/939860)

Alternatively, you can use `RETURNS TABLE (...)`.

Either return type can be used with any `LANGUAGE` (`plpgsql`, `sql`, ...). While you don't need procedural elements provided by PL/pgSQL (or other PL), just pure SQL, it's typically best to stick with plain `LANGUAGE sql` functions. About the language choice:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771561/939860)

I might use a "standard SQL" function for your simple case. See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300507/what-does-begin-atomic-mean-in-a-postgresql-sql-function-procedure/300512#300512)

Comment: I don't understand the rCTE comment, and am happy to ask it as a new question, if you like. All of the tables are the same table. I should have said `sub_temps` for clarity. The intent is to find all temps starting with a given parent `tid`. I could not find a way to refactor this without the `temps.temp_id = tid` going somewhere that limited all results.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. Just that 'aliasing' it as the `start_set` or `start_temp` is unnecesary.  Sure / thanks

Comment: Let's focus this Q&A on the set-returning nature of functions. I'll remove my aside. (It's also partially off target.) If you suspect room for improvement for the query, start a new question with all relevant details for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer, going in the direction of @erwin

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_temps(tid uuid) 
    RETURNS TABLE (temp_id uuid)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY (
    -- ....
    );
END
$$;
```

Keys were:

- use `plpgsql` as the language
- set the return type to `TABLE`
- use correct syntax for this language type, including begin / return query / end

Comment: If there is no more than just the one `SELECT` (with rCTE), a plain `LANGUAGE sql` function would be just as good. And a bit simpler.

Comment: Thanks I clearly have some things to learn about the `LANGUAGE` options.