# User-defined aggregate function to sum jsonb values

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, plpgsql, jsonb

I have agg function that sums decimals. Business logic omitted for brevity

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION calculate_snapshot_internal_decimal(_this_value DECIMAL,
                                                               _next_value DECIMAL
                                                               OUT _code DECIMAL)
    LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN

    _code = _this_value + _next_value;

END
$func$;
```

Now I need the same for JSONB where key is string and value is always BigDecimal

_this_value:

```json
{"weight": "50", "height":"170", "size": "2"}
```

_next_value

```json
{"weight": "40", "height":"20"}
```

aggregated result:

```json
{"weight": "90", "height":"190", "size": "2"}
```

What could I try?

Comment: You skipped a bit too much "for brevity". Only ever aggregate two rows? Which keys to sum up, and how to deal with other keys (if any)? Start by declaring your version of Postgres, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unnest with `jsonb_each_text()`, `UNION ALL`, cast, sum up, then aggregate back with `jsonb_object_agg()`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_jsonb_sum_per_key(_j1 jsonb,_j2 jsonb, OUT _j jsonb)
  LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE
BEGIN ATOMIC
   SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, val)
   FROM  (
      SELECT key, sum(value::numeric) AS val
      FROM  (
         SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(_j1)
         UNION ALL
         SELECT * FROM jsonb_each_text(_j2)
         ) sub1
      GROUP  BY key
      ) sub2;
END;
```

Call:

```
SELECT f_jsonb_sum_per_key(jsonb '{"weight": "50", "height":"170", "size": "2"}'
                         , jsonb '{"weight": "40", "height":"20"}');
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/hEoexkIE)

This sums up all values per key in the two input `jsonb` documents. Values that are not compatible with `numeric` ( = `decimal`) raise an exception.

We don't need PL/pgSQL for this. Plain SQL does it. I chose the standard-SQL variant - your pick. See:

- [What does BEGIN ATOMIC mean in a PostgreSQL SQL function / procedure?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/300507/what-does-begin-atomic-mean-in-a-postgresql-sql-function-procedure/300512#300512)

This is not an ["aggregate function"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-agg.html), strictly speaking, and neither is the example in the question. Both are plain functions aggregating two input values.

Comment: Thanks for details, didn't know it. I'm using pg13, so getting [42P13] ERROR: no function body specified. Anyway it works