# Grant SELECT on all tables in Redshift

Tags: permissions, redshift

I am trying to assign `SELECT` privilege to a group in Redshift. So I created a group and a user in that group:

```
CREATE GROUP data_viewers;
CREATE USER <user> PASSWORD '<password>' IN GROUP data_viewers;
```

Now I would like to allow this group to be able to read data from any table:

```
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA PUBLIC TO GROUP data_viewers;
```

The command returns `GRANT`. Now when I connect to Redshift as my newly created user and issue `SELECT * FROM something.something;` I get:

> permission denied for schema something

I tried granting permissions to something: `GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA something TO GROUP data_viewers;` but this has not changed anything.

---

How can I allow users from my group to `SELECT` data from any table in the schema?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need the `USAGE` privilege (at least) for the ***schema*** as well:

```
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA something TO GROUP data_viewers;
```

Related Postgres example:

- [Permission for sequence in another schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76131/permission-for-sequence-in-another-schema/76160#76160)

Remember you only granted permissions to already existing tables. Does not apply to tables created later. To cover those, too:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR USER role_that_creates_tables
IN SCHEMA public
GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO GROUP data_viewers;
```

[Amazon Redshift implemented `DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` as well.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_DEFAULT_PRIVILEGES.html)

Here is a complete cookbook for Postgres:

- [How to manage DEFAULT PRIVILEGES for USERs on a DATABASE vs SCHEMA?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117109/how-to-manage-default-privileges-for-users-on-a-database-vs-schema/117661#117661)

Be aware of **some differences** between mainline Postgres and Redshift! Redshift sticks to separate *users* and *groups*, while Postgres replaced that with the universal concept of *roles*:

- [Why did PostgreSQL merge users and groups into roles?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8487886/939860)

And I am not sure how Redshift handles sequences ...

Comment: Thank you!! I didn't even know about the concept of `DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` in Redshift before reading this answer! It completely solved the issue for me!

Answer (score 21):

I had the same need for a Redshift read-only user.  After reading the docs, I [came up with](http://jokertechnologies.com/redshift-read-only-users/) a set of queries:

```
-- Create Read-Only Group     
CREATE GROUP ro_group;

-- Create User
CREATE USER ro_user WITH password PASSWORD;

-- Add User to Read-Only Group
ALTER GROUP ro_group ADD USER ro_user;

-- Grant Usage permission to Read-Only Group to specific Schema
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA "ro_schema" TO GROUP ro_group;

-- Grant Select permission to Read-Only Group to specific Schema
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "ro_schema" TO GROUP ro_group;

-- Alter Default Privileges to maintain the permissions on new tables
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA "ro_schema" GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO GROUP ro_group;

-- Revoke CREATE privileges from group
REVOKE CREATE ON SCHEMA "ro_schema" FROM GROUP ro_group;
```

If you want to actually remove the user later on, you have to pretty much go backwards.

Comment: The last revoke on CREATE is actually unnecessary as this permission isn't given by default.